# Accessing the global value outside function

Tags: android, function, global-variables, oncreate

I'm Trying to set a value(global) in a function  and access it outside function that is in "On create()" in android
I've tried making the global variable static, and I even tried to write it in a "edit text" and parsing it in "on create()" . but it keeps initializing to 0.0 (the variable is a double type)
when i tried to access in "on create()",

oh and i can't return the value because the function is too nested so all hierarchy is too complex. :(

Can anyone help me with this;

```
    public class TryActivity extends Activity
    {
        double BAT;\\ global value
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {      
        disp(); // calling the function disp to set the value to BAT                
        String To_string=Double.toString(BAT);    
            System.out.println("Current Battery level  ==="+To_string); \\ prints 0.0 the wrong value
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main); 
           }


     public void disp(){            
        this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));               
        }



        private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){                
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){                  
        double  level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
        BAT=level;
            Textview1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Textview1);
            Textview1.setText(Double.toString(BAT));      // sets the correct value
            System.out.println("bbbattererrerey 1 "+Double.toString(BAT));   //prints the correct value
        }        
    };
}
```

Comment: `OnCreate` is the first thing that runs, so unless you call the function within the `OnCreate` method before referencing the variable, it will have a value of 0.0 (default value). Maybe post some code so I can see exactly what is happening and what you need?

Comment: Please post your code. Your explanation is a bit complicating.

Comment: `and I even tried to write it in a "edit text" and parsing it in "on create()"` ...sounds like a logical problem...

Comment: @FD_ ya seriously i read it three time but did not get anything. Ak- there is no need of defining public and static anything if you want to access in same class, there is something wrong in your logic . As suggested please include you code for the same.

Comment: thanks for reply guys I'm sorry about clarity in question :( I'm new to android and STACKOVERFLOW s....

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize the variable as **public static** gobally in the class. You will be able to access it from anywhere.

Comment: I tried to do so but even if it is GLOBAL (BAT variable) it gets  back to BAT=0.0; even after calling disp(); which modifies the BAT value.

Comment: You cannot have a global variable in an Activity.  By definition, a global value has a life time and scope equal to that of the application.  You are talking about a class field.

Answer (score 1):

Define as public **`static`** your variables:

```
public class TryActivity extends Activity
{ 
public static  double BAT;  //global value.

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...
...
```

You are getting `BAT` with value of `0.0` because when your activity starts execute the method   `onCreate()` and the the method `disp()` that only register the Intent to get the Battery Level.

If you want to get the battery level at the start of your activity you can do it with a function to get the battery level without receiving updates.

```
public float getMyBatteryLevel() {
        Intent batteryIntent = this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        return batteryIntent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    //* Add this method.   
    getMyBatteryLevel()

    disp(); // calling the function disp to set the value to BAT                
    String To_string = Double.toString(BAT);    
    System.out.println("Current Battery level  ==="+To_string); //prints the right battery level.
```

Comment: I don't believe this is an issue of accessing the values from various classes, but rather various functions within the same class, namely the `OnCreate()` method and his user-defined function.

Comment: I tried to make it static apparently when I access BAT value in "onCreate()"   it gives 0.0 before displaying the BAT I called a function disp(); which modifies the BAT value (but BAT value is not changing outside disp(); )                                         and if we try to make it a member of a final class, in final we cannot modify the data members. So i can't set valueof BAT if it's final

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't understand the concept of concurrency. The BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()` won't be called immediately. Thus, you are just setting up the BroadcastReceiver in `disp()`, and not directly touching `BAT`. `BAT` will only be filled with the correct value when `onReceive()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you will look in to your logs the `System.out.println()`  you have written in `onCreate` will be called before the `System.out.println()` written in `onReceive` of your BroadcastReceiver even it is written after your `disp()` method.

**Reason :**

In `disp()` method you are just registering your BroadcastRecever doesn't mean that your BroadcastReceiver is called. It will be called after sometime when your battery level will be changed.

**Solution :**

If you want to do something with yout `BAT` variable define a function in your Activity class and write whole logic inside it like

```
doThings(double batteryLevele){

    //write whatever you want to do with BAT

}
```

and call this function from `onReceive` method of your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: so can't i able to access the BAT value in onCreate() ?     PS: I tried the function "BATsetter(double level){BAT=level;}" in the BroadCastReciever(); but BAT value was still  0.0 in other function(not onCreate()).

Comment: no, because onCreate will be called once and broacast wont be call that time, But y do want to access it in `onCreate()` only you can do whatever you want in a method and call it from your BroadcastReceiver .